# crear una lista única en una web con un formulario

Tags: php, html

necesitaría ayuda para crear un formulario dentro de una pagina web y que se muestren los datos en es misma pagina, la idea es que al introducir el nombre y teléfono en el formulario, aparezca una lista con todos los nombres que se vayan metiendo, pero todo desarrollado en una sola pagina.

yo tengo desarrollado el formulario, y con un echo muestro el valor de las variables, pero al escribir la siguiente linea me sobre escribe la anterior.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" name="frm">

    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Inserta tu nombre" id="nombre"/>
    <input type="text" name="matricula" placeholder="Inserta la matricula" id="matricula"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al mandar los parámetros con post, los guarda en un array y luego lo insertar en otro array para obtener la lista

```
$lista = [];

$nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre']: '';
$matricula= isset($_POST['matricula']) ? $_POST['matricula']: '';

$dato = [
 'nombre' => $nombre,
 'matricula' => $matricula
];

if(sizeof($lista) == 0)
 $lista[] = $dato;
else{
  array_push($lista, $dato);
}
var_dump($lista);
```

En el `action` mandas a la misma pagina, así se recarga y te presenta los datos, ya si deseas que no recargue la página sería un poquito mas avanzado usando ajax y que se te haga sencillo lo harías usando Jquery para las peticiones ajax

Answer (score 1):

Por ahí lo que podrías hacer es mantener en un arreglo javascript y actualizar la vista de la siguiente manera:

```
    <script>
var arreglo = [];

function agregarLista(){
     var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
     var matricula = document.getElementById("matricula").value;
     arreglo.push({"nombre": nombre, "matricula":matricula});
     var lista = document.getElementById("list");
     if (lista == null){
        lista = '';
     }
     lista.innerHTML += '<p>Nombre:</p>'+nombre+'<p>Matricula</p>'+matricula;            
}

</script>
<div id="list">
    Lista
</div>

<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Inserta tu nombre" id="nombre"/>
<input type="text" name="matricula" placeholder="Inserta la matricula" id="matricula"/>
<button onclick='agregarLista()'> Guardar </button>
```

Comment: hola, esta respuesta es escelente, siempre y cuando pudiera usar javascript, pero me piden que solo sea con php, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacerlo a través de AJAX, por:

- Indicas en la zona de comentarios requerir hacer uso de PHP
- Los valores que mandas llegan al servidor lo cual va a provocar que la página del form se recargue
- Como no estás persistiendo los datos en ningún lugar, es decir alguna base de datos entonces cada vez que se recarga la página los valores tecleados se pierden
- Quieres mostrar los datos uno tras otro a medida que el usuario los ingresa en el formulario
- Con AJAX evitarás que la página se recargue

Entonces nuestro proceder debería ser de este modo:

- Obten los valores del formulario, por medio de su `id` a través de la clase `FormData`
- Hacemos uso de la API `fetch` para enviar vía AJAX los datos a un segundo archivo que los procese y retorne los datos como una respuesta
- Asignamos la acción de la llamada AJAX por medio de un botón al cual le impedimos su comportamiento por defecto y evitar que se recargue el contenido
- Los valores de los inputs los pasamos a la clave `body` por medio de la clase ya mencionada (`FormData`)
- Indicamos que el método a usar será `POST`
- Con el método `appendChild()` agregamos el nuevo contenido que se va generando **(los nombres tecleados)** al elemento `lu` que ya fue declarado mas arriba en la estructura HTML
- Desde el segundo archivo .php retornamos con un `echo` el valor de la variable que recibimos por `POST` con una estructura JSON **(esto es opcional)** del modo siguiente: `echo json_encode(["dato" => $usuario]);`
- Accedemos desde JS al valor que nos esta mandando el backend así: `data.dato` donde `dato` es la clave del vector asociativo que esta declarado en el punto anterior

El códifo pudiera quedar así:

**Formulario HTML y código JS para la llamada AJAX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="usuario">
        <button id="btn">Enviar data</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="contenedor">
    </ul>
<script>
    let button = document.getElementById("btn")

    let data = document.getElementById("frm")

    button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch("data.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(data)
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            let lista = document.createElement("li");                 
            let contenido = document.createTextNode(data.dato);
            lista.appendChild(contenido)
            document.getElementById("contenedor").appendChild(lista);
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Archivo `data.php`**

```
<?php 

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];

echo json_encode(["dato" => $usuario]);
```

Dando un resultado en el uso como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencias consultadas**

- [AppendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [CreateTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)
- [CreateElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 0):

Si solo tienes que hacerlo con PHP una solucion seria usar una variable de sesion para que no pierdas los datos, no proble el codigo pero esta es la idea

```
array_push($_SESSION['nombre'], $_POST['nombre']);
array_push($_SESSION['matricula'], $_POST['matricula']);
```